# External bluetooth devices to iphone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, mfi

is it possible to get data from external bluetooth device(not iphone) to iphone(bluetooth sensor to iphone)?because  normally apple requires both end must open the application with same GKsessionID?any help please?will mFI provide special chip t0 install in external device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to the question about getting data from external device.

Se if [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/EAAccessory_class/Reference/Reference.html) helps. I am trying to use the same in one of my project now.

Comment: u did not answer to my question pls..i have asked whether specail chip and license needs or not from MFI.The link provided by you needs MFI License..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean about a special chip, but I can tell you that bluetooth can only be accessed via GameKit, which only works on Apple iOS devices. I'm sure there's some private api, but that would require jailbreaking, which would get your app rejected from Apple right away.

Comment: hi,gamekit needs two iphone, i have asked for iphone to external device(not related to iphone,ipod) we need chip provided by Made for iPod license.

Comment: I've said already - this is only possible via GameKit. Bluetooth on the iPhone has only been made for this and for bluetooth headsets!